# custom fonts with different vertical metrics between OS's

Tags: css, html, fonts, font-face, custom-font

I am trying to include a custom font for a page I am building. My problem is that the font vertical alignment looks different on my ubuntu development machine and on windows pc's.

First, here are the images to understand the problem

*Edit: unfortunately as a new user I cannot post images, so here is a description:*

The issue is the distance between the fonts baseline and the element beneath it. There is an unexplained gap on my ubuntu machine that it's not a padding/margin. Even if you select the text it looks misaligned.

Both tested on Chrome, same html/css behind it of course (it's the same page). No bottom margins/padding both on code and on the inspector tool of chrome. Same line-height. The font is Museo. Both load the .woff version of the font. Any other information, I would be happy to provide.

The css for importing the font is:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Museo-700';
  src: url('path-to-eot');
  src: url('path-to-eot?') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('path-to-woff') format('woff'),
       url('path-to-ttf') format('truetype');  
}
```

The problem persisted even when I removed the woff declaration and ttf was providing the font.

I am really lost with this, no idea how I can make it the same.

Comment: You can post links to images, and someone with more rep can edit them into your post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fonts have three sets of embedded vertical metrics information. One set for Mac, one set for PC and another set typically used by *nix. These can be difficult to synchronize but our Font-face Generator does try to get these values the same. Give it a try?

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

More info from the Google type team:

http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/wiki/VerticalMetricsRecommendations

Comment: I saw your comment too late to be honest, but I had already used your generator and it solved my issue. Excellent tool, thank you very much for providing it to us :)

Comment: Thanks much! Resolved my font metrics issue as well - i obviously used a lousy converter prior to this one.

Comment: Is there any other converter with Vertical Metrics option other than fontsquirrel. As it doesn't let me convert commercial fonts.

Comment: @ImranBughio: Try this https://transfonter.org/

Answer (score 5):

If you can't use FontSquirrel for whatever reason, you can do exactly that locally (even supports Variable fonts).

Download FontTools: https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools

`pip install fonttools`

Also install, Brotli: `pip install brotli`

Now you have the same exact dependencies that FontSquirrel uses on the their servers.  Reload your terminal (close it and reopen it). Now, you should have `ttx` command available in your terminal.

Let's say, we want to fix the vertical metrics for font `foo.woff2` (or woff or ttf or otf):

```
ttx foo.woff2
...
...
```

This will convert it to a human readable font format - `foo.ttx` that you can open in Sublime Text. Search for the "Win" under OS/2 metrics and make sure that they match.

The ones you're searching in this giant xml file are:

- Win Ascent
- Win Descent
- Typo Ascent
- Typo Descent
- HHead Ascent
- HHead Descent

Make Win Ascent = Typo Ascent = HHead Ascent

Make Win Descent = *-*Typo Descent = *-*HHead Descent (note the minus sign. For example, if Typo Descent = -320, Win Descent = 320.

Close `foo.ttx` file and convert it back to ttf using ttx:

```
ttx foo.ttx
...
...
```

There should be a new `foo.ttf` file. We now need to compress it using Google's woff2 library: https://github.com/google/woff2

Follow instructions there and run `woff2_compress foo.ttf` and voila, your woff2 font has clean consistent vertical metrics!

Comment: 1. I couldn't find the hhead ascent and hhead descent fields in my .ttf file. Is that something that all fonts have?
2. Do we need to use google's woff2 library if we want only .ttf fonts?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with this font:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Symbol-Signs

I downloaded the prepackaged @font-face kit and the metrics were inconsistent between Mac and PC.

The solution was to take the TTF font out of the downloaded kit and use it to export a new @font-face kit with Font Squirrel's generator. The generator has a checkbox in the Expert Settings labeled "Fix Vertical Metrics". Make sure this is checked before you generate your kit.

Comment: I had this same problem!!! ZOMG issue twinzzzz!!! Thought I was the only one. The font I had trouble with was: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/antonio

Comment: Did you fix this for Antonio? Because I did what peterhry suggested, regenerate the different webfont files with the "Fix Vertical Metrics" on but the same problem persists...

Answer (score -3):

Set a fixed value, for example in px, for the **line-height** css property.